# What is$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

What is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
I know that 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$ but what about if we add a one to it in the denominator, can we still figure it out?

Comment: $ \frac{1}{2} (π coth(π) - 1)$

Comment: The correct answer is (pi - coth(pi))/2 and that question has been asked before on MSE. I just can't make the link work on my phone. If you put your question in google you can also find a generalization if you replace 1 by $a^2$

Comment: Hint: Consider the function $f(z)=\dfrac{\pi\cot\pi z}{z^2+1}$ over $\Bbb C$ and use the Residue and Estimation Theorems from complex analysis.